# fastbw with rule="p" in R's rms package: why do results depend on number of covariates?

Tags: r, stepwise-regression, regression-strategies, rms

I've been trying to use the fastbw function from the rms package in R to perform logistic regression with backward selection, with p-values as exclusion criterion (I am well aware of the arguments against using p-values for this as opposed to e.g. AIC). However, the results are not in agreement with what I would get if I perform the backward selection manually, as fastbw often drops more factors in comparison. The results also seem to depend on the number of factors considered, even with the option

```
type="individual".
```

I created some simple example data in order to prove my point, which give the following result:

```
> fastbw(lrm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4),rule="p",type="individual")

 Deleted Chi-Sq d.f. P      Residual d.f. P      AIC  
 x3      0.37   1    0.5412 0.37     1    0.5412 -1.63
 x1      1.82   1    0.1771 2.20     2    0.3336 -1.80
 x4      2.58   1    0.1082 4.78     3    0.1889 -1.22
 x2      3.56   1    0.0591 8.34     4    0.0799  0.34

[...]

Factors in Final Model

None
```

I.e., x2 is dropped as the last of the factors considered, resulting in a model without factors. However, if I consider x2 only, I get the following result.

```
> fastbw(lrm(y~x2),rule="p",type="individual")

No Factors Deleted

Factors in Final Model

[1] x2
```

The same is true if I do the backward selection manually, as x2 considered separately has a p-value of 0.045. What might cause this behavior? Since x2 is the last remaining variable in the backward selection, the results shouldn't depend on associations with other model covariates.

Comment: Please use dput() to share your example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using maximum likelihood methods such as logistic regression, the R `rms` `fastbw` function uses an approximation based on sweeping the covariance matrix to produce Wald $\chi^2$ statistics for reduced models.  You notice that the final $P$-value for `x2` as on the 0.05 cusp of "significance".  The disagreement in results is probably due to the model reduction approximation used by `fastbw`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also figured it might be related to the approximation. However, I've seen far worse examples when used with lrm. In a study I'm involved in (N=600), I performed a backward selection in the same way among 33 variables, and the last variable to be dropped (with p=0.051) had a p=0.006 when added manually to the resulting model.

Comment: Note that stepwise regression is an invalid technique unless you use a p-value cutoff larger than 0.5 or so or you use penalization.  With N=600 and 33 candidates your results will not be reliable.